# use Lib.cmd to give commands while logging to stdout

Tags: python, logging, cmd, stdout, stdin

I'm fairly new to python. Now I wrote a python program that does 
A) background checks in one thread, and logs the result of it with logging to stdout. 
And B) also has a Lib.cmd running in a loop to give the program commands.

```
import logging
from cmd import Cmd

class TPrompt(Cmd):
    def do_config(self):
        """prints the current config"""
        print({'loglevel': 20})

def check():
    while True:
        logger.info('Check')
        sleep(1)

def main():
    #start thread for checking 
    t1 = Thread(target=check)
    t1.setDaemon(True)
    t1.start()

    prompt = TPrompt(_conf)
    prompt.use_rawinput = True
    prompt.cmdloop('Starting prompt...')
```

the shell output looks like this:

```
prompt>
2018-01-11 13:02:38 - INFO - Check
config
{'loglevel': 20}
prompt> 2018-01-11 13:02:39 - INFO - Check
2018-01-11 13:02:40 - INFO - Check
con2018-01-11 13:02:46 - INFO - Check
fig
*** Unknown syntax: fig
```

What happens is that the current command is separated by the newline in the log and not valid anymore. Using cmd.use_rawinput does not seem to help. 
Any other thoughts?

Is there a way around?

Thanks!